# Why does mock object have wrong type hint?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

Trying to do a simple mock of Zend_Config for a method that requires a Zend_Config object type, but the mock returns a type of Mock_Zend_Config.

Surely I missed something at this late hour and I am obviously wrong in the function call but I fail to spot my error.

```
$config = $this->getMock("Zend_Config");
```

Returns Mock_Zend_Config, and my object needs to be of type Zend_Config. Looked up the function signature in a cheatsheet and changed the method call to:

```
$config = $this->getMock("Zend_Config", array(), array($confArray),"Zend_Config",true);
```

This version generates a fatal error with message "Zend_Config already exists".

On a sidenote and probably not related to phpunit as such but the typehint does not generate a fatal error as it should , and does so when run without tests.

Any idea of what I'm missing in la mock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mock objects extend the mocked object. A type hint for `Zend_Config` will be satisfied by any class extending `Zend_Config` because by definition a `Mock_Zend_Config` **extends** `Zend_Config` and therefor **is a** `Zend_Config`. Consequently, you will get a Fatal Error when trying to name the mock like the class it extends and none if you dont.

Comment: Just addons: If you _need_ a specific class name use something like "My_Mocked_Zend_Config". Also look into $this->getMockBuilder()->... the API is much nicer than ->getMock()